# strange white line

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

When I try the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/mYx5y/23/

I get a strange white line in the background instead of it all being gray.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens in all browsers, not just IE8. Slightly misleading question.

You need to add `overflow: hidden` to `#tabs` to clear the floats - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mYx5y/24/).

If you want the white gone, also add `background: none` - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mYx5y/28/).

Answer (score 1):

it's the padding of your #tabs div. Change the `padding-top: 10px;` to `margin-top: 10px;` and it's gone.

-edit-

You're right: That's because of the padding that's still set to 10px for all sides. Set the padding and margin of #tabs as follows:

```
padding:10px;
padding-top:0;
margin-top:20px;
padding-bottom:0px
```

The white line will disappear.

Comment: I still get a line, but thinner.

Answer (score 0):

It's coming from the `jquery-ui.css` file `(line 62)`. Just override it with

```
.ui-widget-content { background:transparent; }
.portlet-content { background-color:#fff; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/NA9Xx/2/

Comment: This isn't totally correct. See http://jsfiddle.net/mYx5y/32/ where I only added that single line to the end of the CSS.

Comment: Sorry to whine so much, but this still isn't optimal. It only works when the background color is one solid color, see: http://jsfiddle.net/NA9Xx/4/ - whereas mine works with any background: http://jsfiddle.net/mYx5y/36/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the padding for #tabs to 0...

```
#tabs { border:none; padding:0px; padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;  }
```

Comment: But I need the padding or margin